# How to know if an image file is open

Tags: ruby, unix, lsof

Hello i would like to make a small ruby script to alert me when my image is open.

i try with :

```
filename = "photo.jpg"

loop do
    sleep(1)
    if system %Q[lsof #{filename}]
        puts "File open"
    end
end
```

But it's not working.. any idea ?

Comment: While it is fragile, it works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this example:

1. Create a file `touch hello_world.log`
2. Tail the file with -f (allows you to follow the file in real time as it grows) `tail -f hello_world.log`
3. Open a separate terminal and open up irb

Enter the following code:

```
filename = "hello_world.log"

loop do
    sleep(1)
    if system %Q[lsof #{filename}]
        puts "File open"
    end
end
```

You may wish to have a look at [inotify](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) (Ruby gem [rb-inotify](https://github.com/nex3/rb-inotify)) as this might be what you want instead. Assume a scenario whereby someone opens a file with a text editor and then saves it, the save event might not show up under `lsof` as it's polling every second (and will subsequently only show information that was present at that very point, so you may never catch it).